# How to get system time in nano seconds in Perl?

Tags: perl, time, nanotime

I wanted to get system time in nano seconds in Perl. I tried `Time::HiRes` module and it's supporting only until micro seconds.

Answer (score 6):

The [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) module supports up to microseconds. As @MarcoS answered in the today common hardware is nonsense to use nanosecond precision counted by software.

Two subsequent calls, getting the current microseconds and print both afterwards

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=time -E '$t1=time; $t2=time; printf "%.6f\n", $_ for($t1, $t2)'
```

results (on my system)

```
1411630025.846065
1411630025.846069
```

e.g. only getting the current time  two times and nothing between costs 3-4 microseconds.

If you want some "nanosecond numbers", simply print the time with 9digit precision, like:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=time -E '$t1=time;$t2=time; printf "%.9f\n", $_ for($t1, $t2)'
```

you will get like:

```
1411630910.582282066
1411630910.582283974
```

pretty nanosecond times ;)

Anyway, you can *sleep* with reasonable nanosecond precision. From the doc

> **nanosleep ( $nanoseconds )**
>
> Sleeps for the number of nanoseconds (1e9ths of a second) specified.
>   Returns the number of nanoseconds actually slept (accurate
>   only to microseconds, the nearest thousand of them).
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> Do not expect nanosleep() to be exact down to one nanosecond.
>   Getting even accuracy of one thousand nanoseconds is good.

Comment: Those extra digits are a fantasy, an artefact of converting a binary fraction to a decimal representation with excessive precision. If you don't believe me, try this: `my $t=1411630910.582282066; $t == $t + 0.0000001 and die "not enough precision";`.

Answer (score 3):

The time resolution depends on harwdware clock frequency, of course.
For example, an AMD 5200 has a 2.6Ghz clock, which has 0.4ns interval. The cost of gettimeofday with RDTSCP is 221 cycles: that equals 88ns at best. The minimal cost of a Perl routine will be hundreds times...

So, the final answer is:

On today's hardware, forget nano seconds. With Perl and with any high level language... You can get in that proximity just with assembler, but forget to count single nanoseconds, with software...

Comment: Just because the absolute measurement will be in microseconds for any perl call (that's debatable), for the measurements of _differences_ between two different calls to make sense you still need to have a clock source that has nanosecond level resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental issue is that Perl's Time::HiRes uses an ordinary floating point value to represent the timestamp, usually implemented as a native C `double`, which on many platforms is a 64-bit IEEE float, with a 53-bit mantissa.

That means that timestamps are recorded to a resolution that varies with how far from 1970 they are:

|  | approximate date range | resolution |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 13 Nov 1969 ~ 18 Feb 1970 | less than 0.93ns | *nanosecond resolution available* |
|  | 25 Sep 1969 ~ 08 Apr 1970 | 1.86ns |  |
|  | 20 Jun 1969 ~ 14 Jul 1970 | 3.73ns |  |
|  | 08 Dec 1968 ~ 24 Jan 1971 | 7.45ns |  |
|  | 16 Nov 1967 ~ 16 Feb 1972 | 14.9ns |  |
|  | Jul 1961 ~ Jun 1978 | 29.8ns |  |
|  | 1978~1986 & 1953~1961 | 59.6ns |  |
|  | 1987~2003 & 1936~1952 | 0.119µs |  |
| ► | **2004~2037** & 1902~1935 | 0.238µs | ◄ |
|  | 2038~2105 & 1834~1901 | 0.477µs |  |
|  | 2106~2242 & 1698~1833 | 0.954µs |  |
|  | before 1697 or after 2243 |  | *worse than microsecond resolution* |

Answer (score 1):

**Perl get Time**
 **useing  Time::HiRes**

```
c:\Code>perl -MDateTime::HiRes -E "while (1) {say DateTime::HiRes->now()->strftime('%F %T.%N');}"
```

or

```
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $t = time;
my $date = strftime "%F %T.%N", localtime $t;
$date .= sprintf ".%03d", ($t-int($t))*1000; # without rounding

print $date, "\n";
```

Comment: This answer seems implausible. Even the much later version 5.34.0 does not have a `strftime` with a `%N` format, nor a `localtime` that can accept and return fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The "forget nanoseconds" people are all wrong: perl on normal machines now often returns the same microseconds in subsequent calls, so while atual nanosecond resolution might not (yet) be achievable, you absolutely do need nanoseconds now because microseconds are to coarse.

The above answers are **wrong** - fudging more digits from the imprecision of floats is NOT giving more precision:-

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=time -E 'while(1){my $now=sprintf("%.9f",time); die if($now==$last);$last=$now}'
```

That code does this:

```
Died at -e line 1.
```

Comment: The 2014 postings were right at the time, and those that were qualified by saying "today" (meaning 2014) remain historically correct; saying "all wrong" is itself wrong. That said, I agree that floating point with a 53-bit mantissa has only sufficient precision to represent changes of about 0.25µs when dealing with values around 1.52E9.

Comment: @MartinKealey no, they weren't. To measure difference in execution time of two different calls you still need clock resolution in the nanosecond range. Even if you're running on a first gen Pentium.

Comment: @HubertKario Of course it's *now* true that sub-microsecond resolution is necessary, but to assert that "forget nanoseconds" was wrong at the time it was written is to be myopic about history. As I write this, I'm running the code snippet given in this answer on an older machine (approximately contemporary to when this answer was posted), and it's simply spinning forever: Perl can't issue system calls fast enough to encounter the "same microsecond" issue; switching from `gettimeofday` to `clock_gettime` wouldn't "fix" that.

Comment: For Perl to get the same microsecond value on two successive calls to `gettimeofday` "even if you're running on a first gen Pentium" is just fantasy. Back in 1993, the original Pentium ran at 50~66 MHz, and _just to get into the Kernel_ was of the order of a microsecond using a "software interrupt"; it didn't change to the `sysenter` instruction until 2004. So even C code couldn't make meaningful use of nanoseconds, let alone an interpreted language like Perl.

Comment: Just because op1 takes about a millisecond, and op2 takes about millisecond, _doesn't_ mean that a difference between them can't be measured in individual clock cycles. At 66 MHz it means that a single clock cycle takes 15.(15) ns. So microsecond resolution was already insufficient back in 1993!

Comment: @HubertKario This is just getting nonsensical. To smooth out the jitter inherent in measuring how long a function _in an interpreted language_ takes, you would have to repeat it so many times that µs precision would be ample.

Comment: I have published research where I measured nanosecond differences over the network. Including in interpreted languages. Differences that resulted in something like 30 security vulnerabilities. If you don't want to believe me that higher resolution is useful you're free to do so, but as somebody that has actual need for it, I'll continue to say that `Time::HiRes` is garbage. I'm done here.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, any timer that returns a full UNIX epoch date as a floating point number is useless for sub-microsecond resolution measurements.

While the Linux `clock_gettime` supports a lot of different clock types, using their names in perl is useless too. Even if I specify `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` I still end up with result that's `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Thankfully, it's possible to specify the parameter as integer too, so a call like

```
my $t0 = clock_gettime(2);
```

Will set the `t0` to the current value of `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` timer. Quick tests also suggest that it does provide nanosecond resolution on my system.

The other one that's likely to be fairly precise is the `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` (int id of 7), but that will be less and less precise as the system uptime increases.

So, the real fix would be to change the `clock_gettime` so that it can return the current seconds and current nanoseconds as a pair of integers (just like the `gettimeofday` can).