# Perl DateTime nanoseconds always 0

Tags: perl, datetime

How i can get nanosecond from DateTime in Perl?

I try

```
say DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => time)->nanosecond; # 0
say DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => time)->strftime('%9N'); # 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get system time in nano seconds in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032541/how-to-get-system-time-in-nano-seconds-in-perl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time) returns the number of (whole) *seconds* since the start of the unix epoch. [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) provides a version of `time` with better resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Time::HiRes::time` only gives answers in steps of 2**-22 seconds or 0.24µs. (For a full explanation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66487325/5781773)